# Can't call dictionary function. keyError 0

Tags: python, dictionary

For my comp sci class I was assigned to make an english to pirate dictionary. The user is prompted to enter a sentence which is then translated to pirate but it isn't working and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
eng2pir = {}
eng2pir['sir'] = 'matey'
eng2pir['hotel'] = 'fleabag inn'
eng2pir['restauraunt'] = 'galley'
eng2pir['your'] = 'yer'
eng2pir['hello'] = 'avast'
eng2pir['is'] = 'be'
eng2pir['professor'] = 'foul blaggart'

a = input("Please enter a sentence to be translated into pirate: ")

for x in range(len(a)):
    b = a.replace(x, eng2pir[x])


print(b)
```

Comment: Is your code supposed to replace word by word?

Comment: yeah its supposed to translate word for word :/

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is iterating over `range(len(a))`, so `x` will take on an integer value for each individual *character* in your input. This is off for a couple of reasons:

- Your goal is to iterate over words, not characters.
- Indexing the dictionary should be done with words, not integers (this is the cause of your error).

Finally, note that `.replace()` replaces the first occurrence of the searched item in the string. To revise your approach to this problem in a way that still uses that method, consider these two main changes:

- Iterate over the keys of the dictionary; the words that could potentially be replaced.
- Loop until no such words exist in the input, since replace only does individual changes.

Comment: Thanks! thats really helpful but can you give me an example of how I could iterate over the keys in my code?

Comment: Sure! In this case, your loop would be `for word in eng2pir:`. By default, Python will iterate over the keys in a dictionary. You could also be explicit and specify `eng2pir.keys()` (and there's a corresponding `.values()` method as well).

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over each of the characters in the string input, as the other answer before this has said, `replace` only replaces the first occurence.
You'd want to do something like this (after you've made your dictionary).

```
a = input("Please enter a sentence to be translated into pirate: ")

for x in eng2pir:
    while x in a:
        a = a.replace(x,eng2pir[x])

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

for x in range(len(a)):
    b = a.replace(x, eng2pir[x])

because for loop  x  is int
but eng2pir dict no int key

so output error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''

eng2pir = {}
eng2pir['sir'] = 'matey'
eng2pir['hotel'] = 'fleabag inn'
eng2pir['restauraunt'] = 'galley'
eng2pir['your'] = 'yer'
eng2pir['hello'] = 'avast'
eng2pir['is'] = 'be'
eng2pir['professor'] = 'foul blaggart'

a = input("Please enter a sentence to be translated into pirate:\n ")

lst = a.split()
b = ''
for word in lst:
    b += eng2pir.get(word, "")
print(b)
```